# handling big applications and big databases

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-3-areas

I already have programmed some small applications, the database design was simple, just one normalized database containing all the datas I need for the application.

Now I want to try to programm something bigger:

There should be 4 websites build with MVC3. All the websites should use only one SQL-Membership-Database and some tables like contacts and so on should be shared between the diferent pages too.

**Now my question is: how to start?**

**1.** Should I use one database for all the tables (each application needs up to 40 different tables) including the shared tables like the SQL-Membership-Database or should I create one database for Shared Data, one for Application 1, one for Application 2 and so on?

**2.** Should I put all the Applications into one MVC3-application and just seperate them by using areas?

**3.** All the applications need to save text and pictures, should I use one Table for pictures from Application 1/2/3... and choose them by an application ID or should I create a image-table for each application (same question for texts and descriptions and tooltipps...)?

**4.** My idea was to work woth blob (MS sql 2008 R2) to save files, do you think a good choice?

Is there anyone who have got tipps ore experiances in creating huge (for me its huge ;-)) applications like this?

Comment: You should split this up into specific questions.

Comment: I agree with splitting this up.  In addition the entire membership portion should interact with the other sites as a webservice.

Comment: I've splited my questions you find them under 6547852 and 6548107, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture.

You dont think in mvc o databases thoses just only implementations you should approach in OOP and good Domain Model.

although some point are bad ideas (from my personal point view), how

-save images,text files in databases

now about number of tables that not the point i work on databases of more of 6000 tables, many views and a lot utils the point is your domain model.